# React Multiple Input value in single array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am making a react component which roughly looks like this below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      value: []
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      value: []
    }
  ]);

  const onchangeInput = (val, index) =>{
    let temp = ['',''];
    temp[index] = val.target.value
    console.log(temp)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((value, index) => {
        return <input key={index} onChange={(val)=>{onchangeInput(val, index)}} /> 
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

In function `onchangeInput`  I created an array variable `temp` where I want to store both input values , for example in first input if I insert `first` and in second value if I insert `second` then I want to have the `temp` value to `['first','second']` but everytime if I insert one input item , the other input item is resetting. How can I store both value in my `temp` array ?

Here is a live link [of this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wzyma4?file=src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using data and setData that you define in start of the component.
Change it like this:

```
const onchangeInput = (val, index) => {
    let temp = data;
    temp[index] = val.target.value;
    setData(temp);
    console.log(temp);
  };
```

What I did is temp contains now data which is empty on first time.
setData will save temp contents.

Answer (score 2):

Jon's answer updates the state, but React won't update the UI. A better solution is using `.map` so that you copy the array to a new one instead of getting a reference to the existing one.

```
const onchangeInput = (val, index) => {
    let temp = data.map(i=>i);
    temp[index] = val.target.value;
    setData(temp);
    console.log(temp);
  };
```

Without `map`, you're just editing the original array. Open Node.js and try this:

```
let a = [1,2,3];
let b = a;
b[0] = 0;
console.log(a);
```

Output: `[0,2,3]`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that by using:

```
let temp = ['', ''];
```

You are destroying the contents of it. So, the line after that initializes only 1 element in the array. To fix this, try moving the "let temp = ['', '']" outside of the function.

Ex:

Change this:

```
const onchangeInput = (val, index) =>{
    let temp = ['', ''];
    temp[index] = val.target.value
    console.log(temp)
}
```

To this:

```
let temp = ['', ''];
const onchangeInput = (val, index) =>{
    temp[index] = val.target.value
    console.log(temp)
}
```