# Accessing refs in dynamically created child components react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, use-ref, react-google-maps

How would I go about creating refs on child components created by a map function?

So I'm trying to use

```
"@react-google-maps/api"
```

to create input fields wrapped by google's autocomplete. However I'm running into an issue where I want to allow the user to create inputs (to add waypoints) and the only way to get their input into an arry is by using refs

```
                <div className={style.form}>
                        <Autocomplete>
                            <input type="text" id="from" ref={originRef} placeholder="Enter Starting Location"/>
                        </Autocomplete>
                        {wayPoints.map((input, index) => {
                                return(
                                    <Autocomplete key={index} onChange={e => handleInputChange(index, e)}>
                                        <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Enter Stop"/>
                                    </Autocomplete>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                        <Autocomplete>
                            <input type="text" id="from" ref={destinationRef} placeholder="Enter Ending Location"/>
                        </Autocomplete>

                        <div className={style.add} onClick={addNewStop}>
                            <FaPlus/>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

However since I'm creating child compoents I'm not sure how to use refs to solve the problem. I tried using a onChange handler function but if you click on the autocomplete recommendation it doesnt save.

Comment: Why do you need dynamic refs for this? For every single waypoints you have, whenever the change event is fired you simply set a value in an array by index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Multiple Input value in single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943137/react-multiple-input-value-in-single-array)

Comment: Right but the change event for some reason doesn't fire when a user clicks on an autocomplete suggestion. This leaves only the information they typed to be stored

Comment: Nvm I figuted out that as I could just use document.getElementById. THank you so much for yout help though, cant believe I was so stupid.